# Inner product of elements in an orthonomal set and elements in a Hilbert Space

Tags: hilbert-spaces, orthogonality, orthonormal

Let $\{e_k : k\in K \}$ be an orthonormal set in a Hilbert space $H$, where $K$ is some arbitrary set.

Let $x \in H$.

1. Show that for each $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $F_n = \{ k\in K: |\langle e_k, x\rangle|^2 \geq \frac{1}{n}\}$ is finite. Estimate the size of $F_n$,
2. Show $\{k \in K : |\langle e_k, x\rangle| \ne 0 \}$ is at most countable.

Things I know:

By definition of an orthonormal set, if $e_k \ne x$, then $\langle e_k, x\rangle=0$. Also we have $\| e_k\|=1 $.

Also, the $\{k \in K : |\langle e_k, x\rangle| \ne 0 \}$ is the $(\cup F_n)^c$

From here I'm not sure what to do.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Probably you mean $\langle e_i,e_j\rangle=0$ for $i\ne j$, an arbitrary $x\in H$ need not be orthogonal to the basis elements.
   For any vector $x\in H$ and finite subset $I\subseteq K$ let $x_I$ denote the orthogonal projection of $x$ to ${\rm span}(e_i:i\in I)$, that is,
   $$x_I=\sum_{i\in I}\langle x,e_i\rangle e_i$$
   and because it's a projection of $x$, we have $\|x_I\|\le\|x\|$.
   Now, if $I\subseteq F_n$, then
   $$\|x\|^2\ge\|x_I\|^2=\sum_{i\in I}|\langle x,e_i\rangle|^2\ge\frac{|I|}n$$
   which implies $|I|\le n\,\|x\|^2$.
2. $\{k\in K:\langle x,e_k\rangle\ne 0\}=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}F_n$ and not the complement of the union.
   A countable union of finite sets is countable.

Comment: Thank you for your response! May I ask why do we have the norm of the projection of $x$ less than the norm of $x$, i.e $\| x_I\| \leq \| x\|$?

Comment: If $P$ is an orthogonal projection ($P^2=P^*=P$), then every $x$ is decomposed as $x=Px+(x-Px)$ where $(x-Px)\perp Px$, so that by Pythagorean theorem, $$\|x\|^2=\|Px\|^2+\|x-Px\|^2\ \ge \|Px\|^2\,.$$ Apply it with $P=x\mapsto x_I$.

Comment: So can we say that our estimate of the size of $F_n$ is $n \| x\|^2$?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it can't have bigger subset, so itself has at most $n\|x\|^2$ elements.